# What is an example of a quasicategory with an outer 4-horn which has no filler?

Tags: higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

A quasicategory has fillers for all inner horns $\Lambda^i[n]$ where $n\geq 2$ and $0<i<n$, but it need not have fillers for $i=0$ (or $i=n)$. In particular, for $n=2$ and $n=3$ there are easy counterexamples.

For n=2, let $X=\Delta[2]$ (which is the nerve of a category): there is a map $\Lambda^0[2]\rightarrow\Delta[2]$ that maps vertices $0\mapsto 1$, $1\mapsto 0$, and $2\mapsto 2$, which can't have a filler because there is no arrow from $1$ to $0$ in $\Delta[2]$.

For $n=3$, any small category $X$ which has a morphism $f$ which is not an epimorphism will give us an unfillable $\Lambda^0[3]$. For example, let $X=N(\Delta)$, and consider the maps $f=d^0\colon [0] \rightarrow [1]$ and $g=d^0\circ s^0\colon [1]\rightarrow [1]$. Then we can construct the horn $\Lambda^0[3]$ where the $d_1$-face witnesses the composition $g\circ f = d^0 \circ s^0 \circ d^0 = d^0 = f$, and the $d_2$ and $d_3$ faces witness $\text{id}_{[1]}\circ f = f$. If there were a filler for this horn, then we'd have $\text{id}_{[1]}=g\circ\text{id}_{[1]}=g$, but $g=d^0\circ s^0$ is not the identity.

For $n\geq 4$, a counterexample can't come from the nerve of a category, because nerves of categories are $2$-coskeletal. I've tried to look at other examples of quasicategories—for example, those given in section 8 of [Rezk's notes on quasicategories](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rezk/595-fal16/quasicats.pdf)—but I believe I can show the existence of outer horns for $n\geq 4$ in every example given there.

So, are there any known examples of quasicategories with an unfillable $\Lambda^0[4]$?

Comment: 1. Welcome to MO, Matt! 2. A trivial comment: of course an example can't be a Kan complex either. 3. Have you looked at what happens when you run the small object argument on $\Lambda^0[4]$ itself? 4. For that matter, is $\Lambda^0[4]$ itself a quasicategory?

Comment: Hi Tim! I'm not sure what you mean by running the small object argument on $\Lambda^0[4]$. As for whether $\Lambda^0[4]$ itself is a quasicategory, the $2$-simplices $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3$, $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 4$, and $2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4$ form an inner 3-horn in $\Lambda^0[4]$ which has no filler because $\Lambda^0[4]$ has no 3-simplex $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4$.

Comment: Ah, of course! By running the small object argument, I just mean taking a Joyal-fibrant replacement of $\Lambda^0[4]$. Because the quasicategories are defined in terms of lifting against inner horns, the fibrant replacement can be computed by iteratively filling inner horns, which is to say, by applying the small object argument for the (inner anodyne, inner fibration) factorization system to the map $\Lambda^0[4] \to \Delta[0]$.

Comment: Ah, I understand. An issue I see with that approach is that I think there will be some fibrant replacements in which there actually is a filler, so we'd really have to construct a fibrant replacement explicitly and make sure it has no filler. I'll play around with that a little, but I've been mulling it over for a few minutes and the combinatorics seem daunting.

Comment: How about $\mathcal{N}(\mathfrak{C}(\Lambda^0[4]))$?

Comment: @CharlesRezk Do you intend to take a Bergner-fibrant replacement between the applications of $\mathfrak C$ and $\mathcal N$? Otherwise I don't see why that should be a quasicategory...

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ be any $(2,1)$-category containing a composable pair of morphisms $f\colon a\to b$ and $g \colon b \to c$, and a $2$-cell $\alpha \colon g \to g$ such that $\alpha f = \mathrm{id}_{gf}$. Then the [Roberts--Street--Duskin nerve](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/9/n10/9-10abs.html) $NA$ of $A$ contains a $(4,0)$-horn, described below, which admits a filler if and only if the $2$-cell $\alpha$ is an identity.

To describe this horn, let's first label a few simplices in $NA$. Let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ denote the $2$-simplices in $NA$ given by the $2$-cells $\alpha \colon g \to 1_c\circ g$ and $\mathrm{id}_{gf} \colon gf \to g\circ f$ in $A$. Let $\varepsilon$ denote the $3$-simplex in $NA$ whose boundary faces are
$d_0(\varepsilon) = \beta$, $d_1(\varepsilon) = s_1(gf)$, $d_2(\varepsilon) = d_3(\varepsilon) = \gamma$; this $3$-boundary extends to a $3$-simplex in $NA$ thanks to the equation $\alpha f = \mathrm{id}_{gf}$ in $A$.

The $(4,0)$-horn of interest is as follows:
$$(-,s_1(s_1(gf)),\varepsilon,s_2(\gamma),s_2(\gamma)): \Lambda^0[4] \to NA.$$ By $3$-coskeletality of $NA$, this horn extends to a $4$-simplex in $NA$ if and only if the $3$-boundary $$(s_0(s_0(c)),\beta,s_1(g),s_1(g)) : \partial\Delta[3] \to NA$$ extends to a $3$-simplex in $NA$, which is the case if and only if the $2$-cell $\alpha$ in $A$ is an identity.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to cook up lots of examples. Notice that $\Lambda^n_0 = \Delta^0 \star \partial \Delta^{n-1}$ so that a functor $\Lambda^n_0 \to \mathcal{C}$ is the same as a functor $\partial\Delta^{n-1} \to \mathcal{C}_{x/}$ where $x$ is the image of $\Delta^0$. If we require that the image of the vertices under this functor all map to the same object $y$, then this factors through the fiber over $y$ which is the Kan complex $\mathrm{Map}_{\mathcal{C}}(x,y)$.

So a map $\Lambda^n_0 \to \mathcal{C}$ with this behavior on vertices will have a filler if and only if the resulting homotopy class $S^{n-2} \to \mathrm{Map}_{\mathcal{C}}(x,y)$ is null.

Well now it's easy to cook up examples! Take $\mathcal{C} = \mathsf{Spaces}$, $x = *$, $y = S^{n-2}$, and the functor corresponding to some equivalence $\partial\Delta^{n-1} \simeq \mathrm{Map}_{\mathsf{Spaces}}(*, S^{n-2})$.